# ios firebase ui: license agreement for google provider

Tags: ios, licensing, google-authentication, firebaseui

I can very easily link to an end user license agreement when a user signs up via email:

```
authUI.TOSURL = ...
```

The above code will cause a link to be displayed when the user clicks "Sign in with email"

What is the simplest way to do something similar if the user signs up with Google? Is there a way of showing a link on the main sign up page that would apply to any sign up? Ideally, I would be able to use the api without creating a custom controller. But if not, I wouldn't mind using a Controller that is bare bones.

My motivation for asking this is that Apple requires an end user license agreement for user generated content.

- [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-generated-content)
- [Quora discussion](https://www.quora.com/Apple-App-Store-rejection-category-14-3-help-needed/answer/Matt-Spaulding-3?srid=3Qia)

[image]